# Printing PDF with Batch/vb.net on specific printer

Tags: vb.net, windows, batch-file, printing

I am running a vb.net application that creates about 50-100 .pdf files that I have to print. Since the application will be used 5 days a week i don't want the user to have to select the target printer each time.

For printing I found a decent looking batch-solution for windows, which I will call in my application.

- [[Source]](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php#PrintPDF)
- [[Code]](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/printpdf_nt.txt)

But there is one problem where it comes to my question; My Batch skills arent any higher than `cd c:\myFolder`.

**The Question:**
This batch prints the files to the windows default printer. How can I specify the target printer inside that batch, so I don't have to change the default printer?

I found a solution for selecting the printer using the print command. But for some reason I can't find the place for using it in the batch.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/477910)

> The [`print`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773(v=ws.10).aspx) command uses the following synatx for the `/d:` switch:
>
> > Specifies the printer on which you want to print the job. You can specify a local printer by specifying the port on your computer to which the printer is connected. Valid values for parallel ports are LPT1, LPT2, and LPT3. Valid values for serial ports are COM1, COM2, COM3, and COM4. You can also specify a network printer by its queue name (\ServerName\ShareName). If you do not specify a printer, the print job is sent to LPT1.

Comment: `print` is used for old text printers and the command is left only for backward compatibility

Comment: Sounds like bad news for me. Is there another wait to edit that batch (which seems not to be using the `print` cmd at all after some research so it prints to a specified printer?